# Regression or correlation of time-shifed and time-scaled signals

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

I have 2 digital pseudorandom signals.  The second signal is a copy of the first but it is shifted in time as well as **scaled in time** and has random noise added to it.
In mathspeak: `s1=f(t)` while `s2=f(a*t+c) + noise`.

I begin my sampling of this pair of signals at an arbitrary time `t` thus the relation of this time to the "*beginning*" of the pseudorandom sequence is not known.

When `a=1`, I can just use cross-correlation techniques to find `c`, but `a!=1` throws a monkey wrench into the problem.

What would be the optimal approach to find `a` and `c` given these two signals?
Right now I am brute-forcing many combinations of `a` and `c` and it takes hours on modern computers to find them.

I am not looking for a ready code to solve this. Just a good general algorithm.

P.S.
I can read C and C++ well

Answer (score 1):

There is not much information about your signals (for example, is the length of both signals equal, is your time shift cyclic, or you use zero padding when you do time shift...).But I can give general advice. You can try use some minimization or fitting packet/library. I used with success [MPFIT: A MINPACK-1 Least Squares Fitting Library in C](http://cow.physics.wisc.edu/~craigm/idl/cmpfit.html)  for a task similar to yours.

Your task has 2 parameters - a and c. Your s2 data set is “observed data points” in MPFIT. `f(a*t+c)` - is a model. MPFIT finds the best a and c, which minimize the Least squares of difference between s2 and `f(a*t+c)`. One of the disadvantages of this method is that you must set the initial values for a and b,  but a good initial approximation is usually known.

Comment: The length of these signals cannot be equal when the time scaling factor `a!=1`. The "beginning" of these signals is not known either - in other words, I begin my sampling after an arbitrary time `t` which relation to the beginning of the signal is unknown. Time shift `c` is not cyclic because `s1` is such a long pseudorandom sequence that it is not cyclic for all intents and purposes. However `a` and `c` are constant throughout the signal. When I brute force the solution, I disregard the signals outside of their overlapping zone, after doing the `a*t+c` linear transformation.

Comment: During bruteforcing, I am already using the `least sum of squares` of the time differences between s1's and s2's pulses, **to judge** how close the transformed fit, is.

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson. Minimization/Fitting packet can find minimum of "least sum of squares" much much faster than by brute forcing. Try to use MPFIT (or another packet). This is not very difficult since you have already done half the work - code for calculation of difference between s1 and s2 .